# repeatable read and nolock

Tags: sql-server, nolock

Does anyone know what the net effect of having a block of t-sql with a transaction isolation level of repeatble read and then inside having a select with nolock.

Does the nolock become invalid because the isolation level has already been set?

Answer (score 2):

The table hint in the query takes precedence, as I would have expected.

Here's my test script:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a int);

INSERT INTO t1(a) SELECT TOP 1000 message_id FROM sys.messages;


SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT * FROM t1 WITH(NOLOCK); /* Try it with and without the hint */

    EXEC sp_lock;

ROLLBACK;
```

With the `NOLOCK` hint included, no locks are taken by the `SELECT` statement.

In other words, setting the isolation level on the transaction makes that isolation level the *default within the transaction*, but that default can still be overridden by table hints, as I demonstrated.